# Как создать material анимацию перехода

Tags: android, анимация, material-design, android-animation, transition

Нужно воспроизвести Material Design анимацию https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0B14F_FSUCc01UlJKVG9BVVFuMHM/goodtransition-cleardo-v3.webm с сайта https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition.

Использую фрагменты и анимированный переход с помощью Transition. Но не могу понять как при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView, элемент заполнил все пространство и отодвинул другие элементы